# Asp Net MVC 5 User Identity IsAuthenticated returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication

I'm using forms authentication and creating a ticket

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login([Bind(Include = "Username,Password,RememberMe")]LoginViewModel model)
{
   // other code here ....

    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                        1,
                        user.Id.ToString(),
                        DateTime.Now,
                        DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),
                        model.RememberMe,
                        user.Roles.Select(c => c.Nome).FirstOrDefault(),
                        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
                        );

                    // Encrypt the ticket.
                    string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                    // Create the cookie.
                    HttpCookie authenticationCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket); // Name of auth cookie (it's the name specified in web.config) // Hashed ticket
                    authenticationCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
                    // Add the cookie to the list for outbound response
                    Response.Cookies.Add(authenticationCookie);

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");

    // more code here...
}
```

This is in the Login controller to authenticate user.

Now after this, i try to manually redirect to the login controller

```
 // GET: /Account/Login
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Action("Index");

            return View();
        }
```

and User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns false?? Why is this? I can see the cookie created on browser

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/" timeout="2880" slidingExpiration="true" protection="All" />
</authentication>
```

**EDIT**

Just to say that if i use instead it returns true. I don't understand why it does not work with Ticket

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Id.ToString(), model.RememberMe);
```

Comment: Your code with manually setting auth cookie works fine for me

Comment: you mean the form authentication ticket? It's weird why it returns false on me on is authenticated tho

Comment: Yes. Are you sure? Because I copied your code and it works fine for me, and shows `IsAuthenticated` as `true`. How do you test it?

Comment: after i logged in i just manually wrote on the url bar Account/Login  and see what happened, on debugged it gave me false, this using the form ticket

Comment: Did you have any success with manually setting authentication cookie?

Comment: Please provide debugging environment server and browser, because that can make a difference.